# How to open external command(sqlplus) and use it continuously without restart in Perl

Tags: oracle, perl, sqlplus

I am beginner in Perl script. and am writing perl script which opens external command ( sqlplus ).
I want to open sqlplus with prelim setting, and get session information periodically. That is, After opening sqlplus with (oradebug setmypid) and (oradebug direct_access set mode=unsafe),then I want to send retrieval query(oradebug direct_access select * from x\$ksuse\n) continuously without restart sqlplus.

Following code might make you understand my question better

```
my $set = "oradebug setmypid;\n oradebug direct_access set mode=unsafe;\n oradebug direct_access select * from x\$ksuse\n";
open(PIPE, '|-', "/opt/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_1/bin/sqlplus -prelim system/oracle as sysdba");

print PIPE $set;    #if I call this call continuously, it means I open sqlplus again, again...This is not what I want^^
```

Is there any way of running retrieval query continuously after opening sqlplus once?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Consider [DBD::Oracle](http://search.cpan.org/~timb/DBD-Oracle-1.16/Oracle.pm) as every server installation comes with it.

Answer (score 3):

Generally speaking [Expect](http://search.cpan.org/~rgiersig/Expect/Expect.pod) is rather capable. There  are lots of intricacies to handle when interfacing with an interactive shell command and Expect handles many of them for you.

However I must ask are you certain this (interfacing with sqlplus from perl) is the best approach? I'm not nearly enough of an Oracle expert to understand what your code is wanting to achieve, but have you tried [`sqlplus` start syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a90842/ch4.htm#1006282)

in `query.sql`:

```
oradebug setmypid;
oradebug direct_access set mode=unsafe;
oradebug direct_access select * from x$ksuse;
exit;
```

in shell:

```
/opt/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_1/bin/sqlplus -prelim system/oracle as sysdba @query >data.txt
```

This should put `data.txt` in the current working directory with your results.

Also, perl DBI is rather capable too, although I must  say I don't understand what your code is trying to do so I don't know if DBI is able to help you with that. Google is your friend here.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. But. I just edit my question. If you can give me help for this question, i will be really appreciated

Comment: I think Expect is your best bet here. What it will do is execute the sqlplus command once and help you interact with the stdin and stdout of the sqlplus command programmatically. Here's [one code example](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=110103) to get you started, Google will find more for you.